# why can't print twice deconstruct for this C++ code sample?

Tags: c++, copy

```
using namespace std;

Object returnObject(){
    Object o;  
    return o;  //place A
 }

int main() {
    Object CopiedO=returnObject();  
    return 0;  //Place B
}
```

the object definition is:

```
Object::Object() {
    cout<<"Object::Object"<<endl;
}

Object::~Object() {
    cout<<"Object::~Object"<<endl;
}

Object::Object(const Object& object) {
    cout<<"Object::CopyObject"<<endl;
}
```

the result is:

```
/*Object::Object
Object::~Object*/
```

As I understand, both o and CopiedO in will be deconstructed, but why only once Object::~Object be printed?

I think there is no inline and the copied o is copy of o .but it can't print Object::CopyObject

Comment: This is a fine example of return value optimisation (RVO) at work. :-)

Comment: can you give detailed info for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/13

Comment: Removed my answer saying it was move semantics. That would not be the case because the default move constructor is not automatically generated when you have a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: You can try split the assignment into two lines: `Object CopiedO; CopiedO = returnObject();` and you will see the difference how the optimization works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is eliding the copy. Since it knows that the returned object from the function has as only purpose to initialize `CopiedO`, it is merging both objects into one and you will see only one construction, one destruction and no copy-constructions.